# Indent Subsections (and their content) by one level

Tags: indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I format sections/subsections/etc. like nested lists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2553/how-can-i-format-sections-subsections-etc-like-nested-lists)

I'm trying to get my subsections indented by one level (compared to the main sections). I know the best way to do this is probably to redefine the subsection and add an \hspace but I'm not quite sure how exactly.

```
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\hspace{2cm}{subsection}}
```

Or something similar? Thanks!

Comment: Seems identical to this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2553/how-can-i-format-sections-subsections-etc-like-nested-lists).

Comment: Alex, can you take a look at the question that TH refers to and see if it answers your question.  If so, we'll close this one as a duplicate.  If it doesn't, please explain why it doesn't so that we can better answer your question.